# Save the output of a batch file to CSV

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I have a batch file consisting of 5 thousand curl commands.

I want to append the output to my file, `myfile.csv` in a new column.

So, for example, my curl is:

curl -u "apikey:apikey" "https://www.mywebsite.com/callMethod?url=imageURL.JPG"

The output is a printed JSON response.

Is it possible to simply append this JSON response to `myfile.csv`, so for each new curl it writes to a new row on the same column?

Thanks.

Comment: use [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):`>>myfile.csv curl -u ....`

Comment: @Stephan thanks for your response. If I use the append redirection though, won't it just append to the CSV header column, and not on a new row each time? Thanks.

Comment: Ambigous: `in a new column` <--> `to a new row on the same column` Also you'd have to first process the json data to get the row/column value. I would use powershell for this. (ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet)

Comment: if the JSON response has a linefeed, it will be redirected. Try and if it indeed should just append to the line instead of a new line (I doubt), add a line feed with `echo/`

Comment: it will always be appending at the end of the file, not on the current line of execution. Not sure how do do this in widows batch, and it wouldn't be easy even with *nix shell. When you're talking about 1000's of records, its really better to take the hit, and do this in a programming language and save the data and output into a database. Good luck.